# React Router 4 / IIS / Page Refresh

Tags: reactjs, iis, react-router

I have react app, hosted in IIS. When I run my app outside of IIS, via webpack dev server, I can be on a nested route, such as `site.tld/foo/bar/boo` and when I refresh the page, I stay on this route.

When building my app to run within IIS, refreshing this page causes me to be returned to the root...route.

I am unsure why this is happening as I can only replicate this within IIS.

In order to avoid 404's, I was also forced to add a web.config file to my project in IIS.

During development I simply run a reverse proxy against webpack dev server and the same website in IIS.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>         
      <rewrite>
           <rules>
                <rule name="DynamicContent">
                     <conditions>
                          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
                     </conditions>
                     <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html"/>
                </rule>
           </rules>
      </rewrite>
   </system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```

My routes look as follows

```
import { Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const Routes = () => (
  <Router history={createHistory}>
    <div>
      <SideBar />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/callback" component={Callback} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/search/:tenant" component={EmployeeSearch} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/search" component={Search} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/communications" component={Communications} />
        <PrivateRoute component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>
);

export default Routes;
```

history.js

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

export default createHistory({
  basename: '/admin/',
});
```

Comment: what kind of project is running under iis, MVC?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it works to me , you need to update it on web.config

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL">
    <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="100" />
    <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="404" path="/" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    <error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/error_500.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    <error statusCode="500" subStatusCode="100" path="/error_500.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

reference : [javascript page React-Router URL does not work after manually updating or writing](https://code-examples.net/en/q/1aa2734)